# Custom search box with filters : name + locality

Tags: magento2, javascript, php-7

I am new to magento-2.X, I want to create a custom search box on my sellers listing page, here I want to search by seller's name, and by seller's locality.

Please help me, In advance thank you.

Comment: can you explain how to integrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In order to have the fulltext search :**

You can create your custom search request based on the existent `search_request.xml` file pattern.

Create another request name with your query configuration.

Make sure you index correctly your data in another index called sellers for example.

Then implement your search interface based on this file : `vendor/magento/framework/Search/Search.php`

Then you will be able to search and manage results.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference link if you have @Franck